# Document & Library with Anonymous Access Prompting for Credentials

Tags: list, document-library, anonymous-authentication

I have a SharePoint 2013 Web Application, where I have configured Anonymous Access. At the Site level, I have enabled Anonymous Access for Lists and Libraries. In one of the Libraries, I have broken the inheritance and Enabled Anonymous Access to View Items. The library has 3 files (2 DOCX and 1 XLSX). Even after doing all this, the library prompts for credentials when accessed. Also, I tried to give anonymous access to a single document and removed the anonymous access from the remaining 2 files. After doing this, when I tried to access the file which allows anonymous access, it still prompts for credentials. Not sure if I am missing something. Can anyone please help?

Note: Though I saw some posts with similar issues, none of them seem to have been answered. Hence I am creating a new post.

Answer (score 0):

You must grant anonymous access at the Web Application level, in addition to anonymous access for the specific library/items.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/39217521-f037-4e87-9441-68be1178753a/how-to-grant-anonymous-access-on-sharepoint-document-librarylist-only-not-for-web-application?forum=sharepointdevelopment